# How to get multiple coefficients from a panel data set

Tags: regression, stata

I have a data set with the following variables: ID of an individual, current year, year of graduation, degree, income, and a 0/1 variable to indicate treatment. The income is in the same year as the variable year.

What I want is to regress current income over treatment for every possible combination of: year, year of graduation, and degree.

That means running multiple different regressions that will give me multiple coefficients.

I have zero clues how to do so. I would normally just use:

```
    reg income treatment
```

But this will not give me multiple coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
sysuse auto
statsby, by(foreign rep78): regress mpg weight
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I had a problem with making it work and could not solve it. The proble I have is that one of the variables is created as a function of others and it tells me the following: no; data in memory would be lost